# Marker unclickable underneath a polygon

Tags: google-fusion-tables

I have a fusion table which combines markers and polygons. Sometimes the markers are layered below a polygon and are unclickable. Is there a way to force a marker to appear ABOVE the polygon, so both are clickable?

Example table ID: 3821195

Location is Toronto, Canada. If you zoom in tight, the marker is buried below the polygon.

I've experimented with creating different tables, entering the marker first, or entering the polygon first, but in some cases (eg the table above) the marker is alway underneath the polygon. How come, and how to solve?
Thanks,
Wendy

Answer (score 0):

In the end I put the polygons in one table and the markers in another, and then stacked the layers with the polygon layer on the bottom.

This is the part of the script where the order of the layers were set:

```
    layer1.setMap(map); 
    layer2.setMap(map);  
    layer4.setMap(map);  
    layer3.setMap(map);
```

First one listed is on the bottom. Last one listed is on the top.

Hope this helps somebody else.